# Make Normals explicit with python

Tags: python, normals

I do have a problem with normals in Blender. 
I tried to recreate a script for Blender that we are using in 3Ds Max at work (the original script: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/VertexNormal#SetNormals_MAXScript)

What it should do (and does until normals are recalculated):
It copies the face normals to its vertex normals to get better looking bevels.

**The Code:**

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

for f in bm.faces:
    if f.select:
        fvector = f.normal

        for v in f.verts:
            v.normal = fvector

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, True)
```

**How to use it:**

1. Select the hole object.
2. Shading Smooth (no autosmooth)
3. Entering Edit Mode
4. Select all faces that should not be rounded (everything except the beveled faces)
5. Run the script

It works until I reenter the edit mode of a object.

Is there any way to stop Blender from recalculating the vertex normals?

**Screenshots:**

[image]

Does anyone has a solution for that?

Greetings and thank,
Tobias